# PHP decreasing date('Y-m-d', strtotime(x days')) by (x-1) in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to decrease a counter variable (x) within this date function:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime(x days'))
```

in a while loop like this:

```
$Today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days'));
```

output thus far: 2015-06-25

```
$x = -1;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

$Today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('$x days'));

... 

$x = $x - 1;
}
```

desired output on next iteration of while loop: 2015-06-24 and so on ...

Comment: What you have already will work, except that it has to be done with a double quoted string to interpolate the variable, as in `strtotime("$x days")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have already will work, except that it has to be done with a double quoted string to interpolate the variable, as in `strtotime("$x days")` –  @Michael Berkowski